# how to count child's of parent while dropping the node?

Tags: javascript, jquery

can we show a alert or print in console of child nodes of parent when user drop the node .
In other words when user drop any node to another node I want to show alert of (number of childers) to whom node drop.

here is my fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/fuu94/116/

Please run fiddle expand "c" node.
drag "c-a" and drop on "a"  it show 0(zero) because no children.when it drop on "b" it show 2"two" because that node have two children.

```
$('#tree').jstree({
    core: {
       check_callback: function (op, node, node_parent) {
          return op == 'move_node' ? node_parent.id.indexOf('not') === -1 : true;
       }
    },
    dnd: {
       is_draggable: function (x) {
          return true;
       }
    },
    "plugins": ["dnd"]
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a move_node event. But it triggers after the drop. I guess we can assume the target node had n-1 children before the drop, since jstree doesn't allow dropping a node into its parent.

```
$tree = $('#tree').jstree({
    core: {
        check_callback: function(op, node, node_parent) {
            return op == 'move_node' ? node_parent.id.indexOf('not') === -1 : true;
        }
    },
    dnd: {
        is_draggable: function(x) {
            return true;
        }
    },
    "plugins": ["dnd"]
});
$tree.on('move_node.jstree', function(e, data) {
    target = $tree.jstree('get_node', data.parent, false);
    children = target.children.length-1;
    alert(children);
});
```

Comment: let me explain more , if you drag "c-a" element to "a". it give permission to add node in "a".but if "c-a" element want to add on"b". it will not add .because

Comment: @tutboHz you are thinking in poistive sense .but can we restrict node not to drop if to whom node it drop have child

Comment: @NaveenSharma, I answered the question you asked. You can keep on from here, or ask another question.